# Abbott Exercise 2.6.7

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Assume the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and prove with it the Monotone Convergence Theorem without using the Archimedean Property.

I understand that I cannot use the fact that 1/n converges to zero, but can I use the least upper bound property in the proof or it presupposes the Archimedean Property? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $(a_{n})$ is an increasing and bounded sequence. By Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, it has a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})$, say, $a_{n_{k}}\rightarrow l$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $K$ such that $|a_{n_{k}}-l|<\epsilon$ for all $k\geq K$. For all $n\geq n_{K}$, then $a_{n}\geq a_{n_{K}}\geq l-\epsilon$.

Now we prove that $\sup_{n\geq 1}a_{n}\leq l$, if this can be done, then $l-\epsilon<a_{n}\leq l$ for $n\geq n_{K}$, which shows that both $\sup_{n\geq 1}a_{n}=l$ and $a_{n}\rightarrow l$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

We see that for all $i$ with $n_{k}\leq i\leq n_{k+1}$, since $(a_{n})$ is increasing, then $a_{n_{k}}\leq a_{i}\leq a_{n_{k+1}}$, so $a_{1}\leq a_{2}\leq\cdots\leq a_{n_{k}}\leq a_{n_{k}+1}\leq\cdots\leq a_{n_{k+1}}\leq\cdots$ is then established. Since $a_{n_{k}}<l+\epsilon$ for all $k\geq K$, we get $a_{i}<l+\epsilon$ for all $i=1,2,...$ and hence $\sup_{n\geq 1}a_{n}\leq l+\epsilon$. Since this is true for all $\epsilon>0$, we get $\sup_{n\geq 1}a_{n}\leq l$, we are done.

Pretend that we don't assume the existence of $\sup_{n\geq 1}a_{n}$ at the first place. We still manage to prove that $l+\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $(a_{n})$ for each $\epsilon>0$. We claim that $l$ is an upper bound for $(a_{n})$. Assume that it were not, then there is an $n$ such that $a_{n}>l$. Take $\epsilon=(a_{n}-l)/2$, then by assumption $l+\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $(a_{n})$, in particular, $l+\epsilon>a_{n}$. But $l+\epsilon=l+(a_{n}-l)/2=(a_{n}+l)/2<a_{n}$, a contradiction.

So we establish the fact that $l$ is an upper bound for $(a_{n})$. But for any $\epsilon>0$, by the second paragraph, we can find an $n$ such that $a_{n}>l-\epsilon$, so by the definition of least upper bound, $l$ is really the least upper bound, and we have proved the existence of $\sup_{n\geq 1}a_{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the proof. I'm still unsure if I'm allowed to presuppose the existence of suprema of bounded sets, if I'm not allowed to use the Archimedean Property.

Comment: That a set if upper bounded has the least upper bound is a property of completeness axiom, does that have something to do Archimedean Property?

Comment: @fameros, you may look at my edited post, it may help.

Comment: Thanks again. Last night, before seeing your your edited version, I could use your main argument to deduce the existence of the limit for the main sequence without mention of the sup. Maybe this is totally unnecessary and there is no logical relation between Archimedean property and the completeness of R.